# Swift: How to overwrite values on Firebase Database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need to update or overwrite values on Firebase Realtime.
Here is my code, but every time I write a new task, writes on Firebase with new id and new value.
Needs every time to be just one Id and one value.

```
    let addBudget = UIAlertController(title: "Add Budget", message: "Enter your available budget", preferredStyle: .alert)

    addBudget.addTextField()
    
    let addBudgetAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { (action) in
        if  let newBudget = addBudget.textFields?.first?.text, newBudget.count > 0 {
            self.ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(self.uid!).child("budget")
            let key = self.ref.childByAutoId().key
            let budget = ["id": key, "budget": newBudget]
            self.ref.child(key!).updateChildValues(["id": key!, "budget": newBudget])
            self.eventsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }'''
```

[image]

Comment: You're telling firebase to create a new child with this line: `let key = self.ref.childByAutoId().key`

Comment: @valosip Yes, at first I need to write a child, but then when I press on button to write again, I want to overwrite.

Comment: You just need to keep track of the key generated with this `key = self.ref.childByAutoId().key`. If you use that key as your reference, that node will be overwritten with new data.